# How to get correlations between two variables with lags

Tags: r, loops, correlation

I would like to check if there is a correlation between "birds" & "wolfs" in different lags.Getting the correlation value is easy but how can I address the lag issue ( I need to check the correleation value for 1:4 lags )?  The output that I look for is a data table that contains the lag value and the related correlation value.

```
df <- read.table(text = " day birds    wolfs     
                           0   2       21           
                           1   8         4  
                           2   2         5 
                           3   2         4 
                           4   3         6
                           5   1         12  
                           6   7         10 
                           7   1         9
                           8   2         12 header = TRUE)
```

Output(not real results):
Lag CorValue

```
0     0.9
1     0.8
2     0.7
3     0.9
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do this :

```
corLag<-ccf(df$birds,df$wolfs,lag.max=max(df$day))
```

it will return this :

Autocorrelations of series ‘X’, by lag

```
-8     -7     -6     -5     -4     -3     -2     -1      0      1      2      3      4      5      6     7      8  
-0.028  0.123 -0.045 -0.019  0.145 -0.176 -0.082 -0.126 -0.296  0.757 -0.134 -0.180  0.070 -0.272  0.549 -0.170 -0.117
```

the first row is the lag, the second is the correlation value. you can check that `cor(df$birds,df$wolfs)`is indeed equal to -0.296

Comment: Hello @etienne, Is there a way to limit the number of lags? for example I have 1k time points but I would like to check the correlation of lags 1:10 ? I tried: corLag$ccf[1:10] but without success.

Comment: Yes there is : `lag.max=10` instead of `max(df$day)`. it returns the lags from -10 to +10

Comment: And then you can use `corLag[0:10]`to have the correlation and the correlation with lags from 1 to 10

Comment: That's great @etienne, Thanks again

Comment: is there a good way to plot these?